# Lwc controller apex test class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, test-setup

Say I haven apex class that is being used in a lwc to bring in the name of a group via a wired method to variable accid. The apex class looks something like this.

```
Public controllerclass {
   Public Controllermethod group__c (Id accid){

   Account  acc = [select id,group__c 
   from account 
   where Id =: accid];

  Group__c grp = [select id, name from 
  group__c 
  where team__c =acc[0].Id; 

  Return grp;
   } 
 }
```

From here on in the lwc I use the name from the result of grp.

My question is the following.

Is it possible in the apex test class to test if the value in the controller is the correct one? I have already created some test data and grp has a record created and queried in the test method.
Say I wanna do

```
`Asserts.equals(grp.name,controllerclass.controllermethod(grp.name)`
```

is this possible? If not how would you write the test class?

How would I test to make sure the value In The controller is the right one using asserts.

The assert method does not work when I add the `controller.method()` it says wrong type.

Comment: You've oversimplified your code; it has a number of issues that make it virtually impossible to tell what you really wrote. In general, you call an `@AuraEnabled` method the same as any other. You make sure you have the correct context (static), the correct parameters, and then you check for the correct return value. If you want to write a closer approximation to your actual code, we'd be able to give you more specific guidance. You can [edit] your question to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be able to test this scenario. What you have to do is, before calling your controller.method() in the test class, you must create the test data, meaning you must insert an account and a group that is related to that account.
Something like:

```
@isTest
public class myTestCls{
    @isTest
    public static void myTestMethod(){
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'test acc');
        insert acc;

        Group grp = new Group(Name = 'test grp', Team__c = acc.Id);
        insert grp;

        controllerclass ctrl = new controllerclass();
        ctrl.method(acc.Id);
    }
}
```